# SetWindowPos behaviour for Notepad.exe on multi-moniter setup

Tags: winapi, window

I am trying to move the Notepad window using the [`SetWindowPos()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) Win32 API.

When I pass `x/left = -1`, instead of only moving the window in x-direction, it also changes the y/top of the window (window sort of creeps upward). This only happens in a multi-monitor setup.

`x=0` multi-monitor:

[image]

`x=-1` multi-monitor:

[image]

In a single monitor setup, it is moving the window in the x-direction as expected:

`x=-1` single-monitor:

[image]

Also, I created my own simple window (using Visual Studio's wizard-generated code) and it works as expected (y/top did not change) even in a multi-monitor setup.

`x=0` multi-monitor:

[image]

`x=-1` multi-monitor:

[image]

*I observed the same behaviour in Chrome/Brave/MSEdge windows as well in a multi-monitor setup.*

I tried to install `WH_CALLWNDPROC` and `WH_GETMESSAGE` hooks, and used Spy++, but I didn't get any useful information about what is happening.

TEST:

Make sure `notepad.exe` is running.

For simplicity, I will use Python and will require `win32gui` and `win32con`

> pip install pywin32

```py
import win32gui
import win32con

notepadHwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Notepad", None)

// => x = 0
win32gui.SetWindowPos(notepadHwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, 0, 200, 200, 100, win32con.SWP_NOREDRAW)

win32gui.GetWindowRect(notepadHwnd)
// (0, 200, 200, 300)

// => x = -1
win32gui.SetWindowPos(notepadHwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, -1, 200, 200, 100, win32con.SWP_NOREDRAW)

win32gui.GetWindowRect(notepadHwnd)
// (-1, 160, 199, 300) 160??????????????
```

Is this behaviour implementation-specific? Any explanation as to why this is the case?

Both of the monitors are 1920x1080.

Update:
The y/top parameters effects how much y/top itself gets changed when `x=-1` is specified e.g.

`when y=0, then change in y'=0`

```
>>> win32gui.SetWindowPos(notepadHwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, -1, 0, 200, 100, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
>>> win32gui.GetWindowRect(notepadHwnd)
(-1, 0, 199, 100)
```

`when y=60, then change in y'=48`

```
>>> win32gui.SetWindowPos(notepadHwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, -1, 60, 200, 100, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
>>> win32gui.GetWindowRect(notepadHwnd)
(-1, 48, 199, 160)
```

`when y=600, then change in y'=480`

```
>>> win32gui.SetWindowPos(notepadHwnd, win32con.HWND_TOP, -1, 600, 200, 100, win32con.SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
>>> win32gui.GetWindowRect(notepadHwnd)
(-1, 480, 199, 700)
```

Comment: Dpi related? Your two monitors do not have the same dpi? Does the same happen with a dpi unaware application?

Comment: probably not DPI related because when the window actually crosses the monitor boundary it kind of get zoom-in/magnified as usual. When I move the window with my mouse, the y/top does not change meaning the issue does not occur. It only happens when I try to change position using SetWindowPos api.

Comment: here is the magnifying effect I mentioned in my comment above:
https://imgur.com/PIykc44  and  https://imgur.com/RpOLc9s

Comment: Will the same problem occur with MoveWindow?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-movewindow

Comment: Yes issue occurs with SetWindowPos, MoveWindow and SetWindowPlacement. Are there any other APIs to reposition a window?

Comment: I can only do a single-monitor test at the moment. I used the same parameters as you in the test. There are some characters in the notepad, but I can't get the result in your first picture (after setting the size, Notepad becomes smaller, characters inside are hidden), there is a critical value for the length and width of the form, no matter how much I try to shrink the form, I can always see the characters in the notepad. Is it the same when you test on a single monitor?

Comment: I can shrink the form upto the titlebar (meaning client area can be shrink to 0 height.

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation using the C++ console program, you can see my reply to you on MS Q&A. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/807588/setwindowpos-behaviour-for-notepadexe-on-multi-mon.html